# Responsive menu won't close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some problems with my responsive menu. I can't get it to go up again when I click on a link. I have used some Ajax and jQuery to make the menu sites stay on the front page, but I just can't figure out what is wrong?

The site can be seen here: www.sverkel.dk/m_index.php

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>

    <center><img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ykaurc.jpg"></center>

</div>

<div class="handle"><img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/mn0w95.jpg"></div>

<nav>

    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="produkter">Produkter</a></li>
    <li><a href="priser">Priser</a></li>
    <li><a href="om">Om os</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>


</nav>

<section>

<script>

    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');

        });

</script>

</section>

<div class="tekst" align="center" id="content"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/general.js"></script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: arial;


}


img, object {
max-height: 100%; 
max-width: 100%;


}


.i {

text-align: left;
padding: 1px 15px;



}


a {

text-decoration: none;
color:inherit;  


}


nav ul {

background-color: #a34949;
overflow: hidden;
color: white;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
transition: max-height 0.4s;

}


nav ul li {

display:inline-block;
padding: 20px;
border-top:1px solid #fff;


}


nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #ae3a43;


}


section {

line-height: 1.5em; 
font-size: 0.9em;
padding: 10px;
width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;


}


.handle {
width: 100%;
background: #a34949;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
box-sizing:border-box;
padding: 10px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
display: block!important;


}


@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

nav ul {
max-height: 0;


}

.showing{
max-height: 20em;

}


nav ul li {

box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
text-align: left;

}


.handle {
display:block;

}

}
```

Comment: please provide more details about what problem your facing

Comment: Sorry. When on the mobile page on your smartphone the menu won't go back up when i click on one of the menu items. The menu just stays down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <center><img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ykaurc.jpg"></center>
    </div>

    <div class="handle"><img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/mn0w95.jpg">
        <nav>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="index">Forside</a></li>
                <li><a href="produkter">Produkter</a></li>
                <li><a href="priser">Priser</a></li>
                <li><a href="om">Om os</a></li>
                <li><a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="tekst" align="center" id="content"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/general.js"></script>
```

general.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // toggle menu
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });

    // load index page
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');

    // load clicked page
    $('#nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        // trigger the toggle so it closes
        $('.handle').trigger('click');

        var page = $(this).attr('href');

        // do load
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hoo5nzfu/3/

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but it still won't work :(

Comment: @Sverkel try using `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`!

Comment: I have tried different things with the return false, but nothing is working, not even the e.preventDefault() ??

Comment: When I try the e.preventDefault() my links just go to a Not Found page?

Comment: I have left the code with the e.prevent and 'nav' in the handle div so you can see what I mean.

Comment: It still won't work. I have tried to correct my code with the one you provided, but the menu still won't go up no matter what I do?

Just to be sure, this part, where do you wan't this? In the .js or in my php with the other part of the script?



$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    console.log("toggle");
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});

$('#content').html("index");

$('#nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

 console.log("click.a", page);
    $('#content').html("content/" + page + '.php');

    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: only using the js in jsfiddle. You can put it on your php and remove the .js file.

Comment: updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hoo5nzfu/2/
this one use return fase. I tried it on my smartphone and works just fine.

Comment: Great, that works, but now it just post the name of the site and not the content of the site?

Comment: sorry; replace $('content').html(...) with your code( $('#content').load(...) )

Comment: Sorry i'm slow, I don't follow you?

Comment: This is my js file:

$(document).ready(function() {
 // initial
 $('#content').load('content/index.php');
 
 // handle menu clicks
 $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
  return false;

 });
});

Comment: Yes but with what? I can't see to wrap my mind around what to do?

Comment: your html should be like the one above. You should create a general.js again and put the js above in it!.

Comment: I don't know if you saw it, but I've update my role post with the final code. Just replace all inside your body with the one above, plus update your general.js with the one above(post). All should works fine now.

Comment: So in my php doc i place:

$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    console.log("toggle");
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});

$('#content').html("index");

$('#nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

 console.log("click.a", page);
    $('#content').html("content/" + page + '.php');

    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I just can't get it to work? Would you explain one more time, what code needs to go where?

Comment: GOT IT! GOT IT! GOT IT! THANK YOU! :D:D

Comment: if it helped you, please mark my post as an answer :P

Comment: Will do as soon I get home

Comment: Thank you so much everyone who helped me! :D

Answer (score 2):

Your toggle is on the handle, which is the icon bar only. 
If you want the behaviour to happen on clicking anywhere in the nav, you should add it to the selector.

```
$('.handle, nav').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});
```

Comment: If I do this the menu goes up and down when I click/tab but it does not work if i click/tab on the menu link text, if I press next to the text the menu goes up and down.

Comment: it works for me wherever I click, it also goes to the specified url. What browser are you on? http://jsfiddle.net/kt4jrqzq/

Comment: I have tried Safari and Chrome on iOS and Mac OS and Internet Explorer and Chrome in Windows 10, none of them work. It also is not working right in the jsfiddle you are linking to. There you can't see the text.

Comment: Do you resize your window to a narrow iphone-like view when testing it?

Comment: Yes I do. I have also tested it in Chromes simulator with all type of devices. I have tested with my own iPhone 6, my friends Samsung Galaxy S6 EDGE an iPad and a Windows Phone. If you go to the site www.sverkel.dk/m_index.php right now on your device you can see the error. The e.preventDefault() brakes the links so they don't work, they just go to a Not Found page and the nav in the handle script makes it go up and down when click or tab next to the link but if you click or tab the link text the link goes to that Not Found page.

Comment: That's another issue. The animation is working perfectly now (wasn't it the initial question?). Your links don't seem valid. Replace <a href="index">Forside</a> with <a href="http://www.google.com">Forside</a> and it goes to that page.

Comment: My problem is the menu won't close and it still won't even if I replace the e.preventDefault() with the return false; then my links are working but the menu won't go up. Take a look now. Now my links are working, but the menu stays down.